# MS CRM filtered view query works in management studio but not in SSRS report wizard

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, reporting-services

I'm creating a report using SSRS BIDS. My query is not working in the report wizard although it is working in SQL Management Studio. I'm using SQL 2008 R2 and CRM 2011. **Query** is below

```
SELECT     
FilteredBRE_licensee.bre_licensee AS Licensee, 
CONVERT(varchar, FilteredBRE_licensee.bre_agreementdate, 101) AS [Agreement Day],              
FilteredBRE_keyhistory.bre_keynumber_pk AS [Key], 
FilteredBRE_keyhistory.bre_numoflicenses AS [# of licenses], 
FilteredBRE_keyhistory.bre_billingdetailidname AS [Billing Detail], 
FilteredBRE_keyhistory.bre_sendtoaccountidname AS [Account Name], 
FilteredBRE_keyhistory.bre_assignedtocontactidname AS [Assigned To Contact], 
FilteredBRE_keyhistory.bre_sendtoaccountidname AS [Account Name], 
FilteredBRE_keyhistory.bre_sendtocontactidname AS [Send To Contact], 
FilteredBRE_keyhistory.bre_billingcyclename AS [Billing Cycle], 
FilteredBRE_licensee.bre_networkminimum AS [Network Minimum], 
FilteredBRE_licensee.bre_networkoption AS [Network Option], 
FilteredBRE_licensee.bre_pcoption AS [PC Option], 
FilteredBRE_licensee.bre_combinedminimum AS [Combined Minimum], 
FilteredBRE_licensee.bre_pcoptionname AS [PC Option Name], 
FilteredAccount.bre_billing_address_line1 AS [Account Address Line 1], 
FilteredAccount.bre_billing_address_line2 AS [Account Address Line 2], 
FilteredAccount.bre_billing_address_line3 AS [Account Address Line 3], 
FilteredAccount.bre_billing_address_city AS [Account Address City], 
FilteredAccount.bre_billing_address_stateorprovince AS [Account Address State], 
FilteredAccount.bre_billing_address_postalcode AS [Account Address Zip], 
FilteredAccount.bre_billing_address_countryname AS [Account Address Country], 
Billing_Contact.bre_billing_address_line1 AS [Billing Contact Address Line 1], 
Billing_Contact.bre_billing_address_line2 AS [Billing Contact Address Line 2], 
Billing_Contact.bre_billing_address_line3 AS [Billing Contact Address Line 3], 
Billing_Contact.bre_billing_address_city AS [Billing Contact Address City], 
Billing_Contact.bre_billing_address_stateorprovince AS [Billing Contact Address State], 
Billing_Contact.bre_billing_address_postalcode AS [Billing Contact Address Zip], 
Billing_Contact.bre_billing_address_countryname AS [Billing Contact Address Country], 
Send_To_Contact.bre_billing_address_line1 AS [Send To Contact Address Line 1], 
Send_To_Contact.bre_billing_address_line2 AS [Send To Contact Address Line 2], 
Send_To_Contact.bre_billing_address_line3 AS [Send To Contact Address Line 3], 
Send_To_Contact.bre_billing_address_city AS [Send To Contact Address City], 
Send_To_Contact.bre_billing_address_stateorprovince AS [Send To Contact Address State], 
Send_To_Contact.bre_billing_address_postalcode AS [Send To Contact Address Zip], 
Send_To_Contact.bre_billing_address_countryname AS [Send To Contact Address Country]

FROM
FilteredBRE_keyhistory 
INNER JOIN FilteredBRE_licensee ON FilteredBRE_keyhistory.bre_licenseeid =         FilteredBRE_licensee.bre_licenseeid 
INNER JOIN FilteredBRE_billingdetails ON FilteredBRE_licensee.organizationid =     FilteredBRE_billingdetails.organizationid 
INNER JOIN FilteredContact AS Billing_Contact ON FilteredBRE_billingdetails.bre_billingcontactid = Billing_Contact.contactid 
INNER JOIN FilteredAccount ON FilteredBRE_billingdetails.bre_customeraccountid = FilteredAccount.accountid 
INNER JOIN FilteredContact AS Send_To_Contact ON FilteredBRE_keyhistory.bre_sendtocontactid = Send_To_Contact.contactid
WHERE     (FilteredBRE_keyhistory.bre_iscurrent = 1) AND (FilteredBRE_keyhistory.bre_status = 1)
```

**The error**

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Report Designer

An error occurred while the query design method was being saved. An item with the same key has already been added.

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Comment: What do you mean by: "My query is not working in the report wizard although it is working in SQL Management Studio." When does the error occurs when you upload the .rdl file in a report. Or when you run the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Query Account Name is specified twice in select list 
"FilteredBRE_keyhistory.bre_sendtoaccountidname AS [Account Name]". Please remove it or give different alias names. Then it will work fine... :)